# WinRT camera preview processing

Tags: image-processing, camera, windows-runtime

Is there any way to overlay an image on the camera preview in WinRT?

I am building an app where the camera needs to be focused on a specific spot by user, and I need user to see the rectangle in the center of the camera preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. Simply place any element on top of the preview element. I just created a very simple sample app. You can find it here: https://github.com/DanielMeixner/so/tree/master/CameraOverlay/App1